# Отрицательные значения типа signed char в С

Tags: c

Есть такой тип Signed Char. Он имеет диапазон -127...127. Если Char это символ, то как символ может быть отрицательным? И в каком случае принципиально использовать signed а в каком unsigned char?

Вот например есть код функции сравнивающей 2 строки:

```
int ft_strncmp(const char *s1, const char *s2, size_t n)
{
    size_t  i;

    i = 0;
    if (n == 0)
        return (0);
    while ((i < n) && (s1[i] || s2[i]))
    {
        if (s1[i] != s2[i])
            return (((unsigned char)s1[i] - (unsigned char)s2[i]));
/*Почему здесь используется приведение к типу unsigned char? */
        i++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: Отрицательный не символ, а его код. Даже не так — трактовка его кода как знакового или беззнакового значения. Сам символ — это просто иное представление числа. В вашем коде приведение делается для того, чтоб получить правильный знак результата, не зависящий от того, знаковый или беззнаковый char использует компилятор.

Comment: Если вам нужны маленькие числа со знаком, то используйте `signed char`, если без знака, то `unsigned char`. Обратите внимание, что просто тип `char` может быть как знаковым, так и беззнаковым. Например, в системах для x86 он (по крайней мере в GCC) обычно знаковый, а в ARM беззнаковый. Поэтому в своих программах, если используете `char` переменную как индекс в массиве, то имеет смысл добавлять к такому индексу приведение типа к  `unsigned char`, например, `char x; ... v = small_array[(unsigned char)x]; `

Comment: О вашем вопросе -- *`"Почему здесь используется приведение к типу unsigned char?"`* -- потому что требуется вернуть результат < 0, если строка s1 меньше чем s2, 0 -- если они равны и > 0 если s1 > s2. Сравниваются коды символов, все они рассматриваются как положительные числа от 0 до 255 (см [man strcmp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcmp.3.html))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Char это целочисленный тип данных, с установленным размером в 1 байт(всегда в яп С/С++).  В СИ в данном случае этот тип данных может использоваться для хранения кода символа. Данный код определяется таблицей кодировки
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так вот данный код может быть любым численным значение.
PS char(знаковый) это от -128 до 127 
PSS вы можете проверить код символа примерно так:

```
int main(){
   char a = 'A';
   printf("symbol is %c and code of symb = %d",a,a);
}
```

Comment: Вы привели таблицу для беззнакового `char` :) Добавьте пояснение, что знаковое и беззнаковое в битовом виде — это одно и то же, вопрос в трактовке старшего бита — как бита значения, или как бита знака...

Comment: то есть 256 символов от 0 до 256 те же самые что и от -128 до 127? Я попробовал вывести символ для -65 и ничего не получилось: ` int main(){
   int b = -65;   
  printf("symbol is %c and code of symb = %d",b,b);
  return 0;
} `

Comment: Как узнать символ для отрицательного значения? Я нигде не нашел ascii таблицу для отрицательных символов...

Comment: @JohnnyLeet Посмотрите, например, на [cp-1251](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) (кодировка для Windows). (-1 = 0xff, -2 = 0xfe, ... -128 = 0x80) (можете попробовать `int main () {   for (int i = -128; i < 0; i++)     printf("%4d  0x%02x <%c>\n", i, i & 0xff, i); }` Если у вас Linux, то установите в эмуляторе терминала *`Terminal-->SetCharacterEncoding-->WINDOWS-1251`*)

Comment: @Harry вопрос не в трактовке старшего бита. В си отрицательные числа хранятся в дополнительном двоичном коде, поэтому одной трактовкой тут не обойдётся. Если 1 будет 00000001, то -1 никак не 10000001, -1 будет 11111111. Соответственно это никак не вопрос " трактовки старшего бита — как бита значения, или как бита знака". Я могу согласиться что это вопрос трактовки если старший бит трактовать либо как 2^8(прямой двоичный код), либо как (-1) * (2^8)(дополнительный двоичный код). Однако вероятно это следовало бы пояснить в ответе, это дополнение очень уместно :)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы было понятнее, выполните вот такой простенький код:

```
for(unsigned int uc = 0;;uc++)
{
    printf("%3i    %c    %3i\n", uc, (char)uc, (signed char)uc);
    if (uc == 0xFF) break;
}
```

Видите? Это три разных представления одного и того же содержимого байта в памяти. Весь вопрос просто в том, как он *трактуется*.