# Объясните как это работает

Tags: c++, char, int

Не понимаю почему именно такие результаты выводит. Простой интерес, практического применения не вижу

```
int main()
{   
    cout << 4 + "0" << "\n";
    cout << 8 + "0" << "\n";
    cout << 12 + "0" << "\n";
    cout << 12 + "0" << "\n";
    cout << 16 + "0" << "\n";

    cout << "h"- "0" << "\n";
    cout << "e" - "0" << "\n";
    cout << "l" - "0" << "\n";
    cout << "l" - "0" << "\n";
    cout << "o" - "0" << "\n";
    cout << "g" - "0" << "\n";
    cout << "l" - "0" << "\n";



}
```

выводит
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш код выводит h
l
g
g
8
4
6
8
8
10
12
8, а содержимое картинки не совпадает с выводом, покажите весь код

Comment: @АнонимныйПаша Это [UB](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Неопределённое_поведение). Неудивительно, что у вас другой вывод

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1478832/%d0%9e%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%86%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bf%d0%b0-signed-char-%d0%b2-%d0%a1/1478840#1478840

Comment: @SpaceResearcher Как это относится к вопросу?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы столкнулись с [неопределённым поведением](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). То, что вы видите, может меняться от компилятора к компилятору, и от компьютера к компьютеру.

В своём коде вы складываете и вычитаете не строки, а указатели на эти строки:

```cpp
4 + "0";    // const char*
"h" - "0"   // ptrdiff_t
```

В первом случае вы получаете указатель на некоторый участок памяти. И пробуете вывести строку, начинающуюся с этого участка. Компьютер будет пытаться представить байты этой памяти как символы в некоторой кодировке до тех пор, пока не встретит [нуль-терминатор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0).

Скорее всего, ваш компилятор поместил строки `"0"`, `"h"`, `"e"`, `"l"`, `"o"`, `"g"` достаточно близко в памяти. Строка `"0"` находится раньше всех. И когда вы прибавляете к её указателю небольшое число, вы попадаете на строку `"h"`.

Обратите внимание, что я говорю именно *строки*, не *символы*. Потому что `"h"` содержит 2 символа — `'h'` и `'\0'`. Последний как раз и представляет собой нуль-терминатор. И если вы попадаете указателем в `'h'`, то компьютер заканчивает печать на следующем же символе.

Во втором случае результат выражения неявно приводится к числу. И вы просто видите разницу между указателями.

Comment: Только `ptrdiff_t`, не `long`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Спасибо за уточнение

Answer (score 2):

Стало интересно повторить. Итак, на VC++ это достигается, например, так:

```
const char * m[] = {"0","h","e","l","o"};

int main()
{   
    cout << 4 + "0" << "\n";
    cout << 8 + "0" << "\n";
    cout << 12 + "0" << "\n";
    cout << 12 + "0" << "\n";
    cout << 16 + "0" << "\n";
}
```

Но! обязательно должна быть включена (вернее, не отключена) опция `/GF` (*включить объединение строк только для чтения*). Стоит скомпилировать как `/GF-`, как все `"0"` становятся разными и всё становится очень грустно...

Answer (score 1):

Вы складываете и вычитаете указатели.

Вычитание работает правильно только если указатели указывают на элементы одного и того же массива (`&a[i] - &a[j] == i - j`), иначе вы получаете неопределенное поведение. В вашем примере они указывают на первые элементы разных массивов, поэтому поведение не определено.

А сложение работает так: `&a[i] + x == &a[i + x]`. Если индекс получившегося элемента выходит за границы массива, опять же происходит неопределенное поведение, как в вашем случае.

---

Почему вы видите именно такие числа? Потому что компилятор поместил все ваши строки рядом в памяти. Грубо говоря, там что-то типа массива `const char x[] = {'0','\0','h','\0','e', ...};` Конкретный порядок строк стандартом не гарантируется, как и то, что они будут в памяти рядом, и то, будут ли повторяющиеся строки иметь разные адреса.

Здесь `"h"` превращается в `&x[2]`, и т.п. Дальше подставляете результат в формулы выше. Можете поэкспериментировать с порядком элементов в массиве, чтобы получить такие же числа, как у вас сейчас.